# SQL send db mail to multiple recipients with each related data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a two stored procedures, one holding the data info and the other is more for the call of db mail. I have a samples of the second stored procedure below as the issues is  there.

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Coord_ID varchar(20)
declare @Coord_Name varchar(25)
declare @Coord_Email varchar(75)
declare @CoordCursor as cursor
declare @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)
declare @emailBody varchar(100)

declare @sqlCommand varchar(1000) = 'sp_MZ_Get'
declare @qry varchar(1000)

set @CoordCursor = cursor Fast_Forward for
select distinct TARGET_ID, FULL_NAME, Email from vw_Coords where Email <> '' --and Target_ID = '7000001'

open @CoordCursor
fetch next from @CoordCursor into @Coord_ID,@Coord_Name, @Coord_Email
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    Print @Coord_ID + ' ' + @Coord_Email


    set @emailBody = 'Member Renewal Transaction Activity for '+ @Coord_Name

    DECLARE @RenewalActivity TABLE
    (
        Membership_Type varchar(25),
        Member_ID varchar(20),
        Chapter varchar(20),
        Full_Name varchar(35),
        Transaction_Date smalldatetime,
        Renewal_Date smalldatetime,
        AC_ID varchar(10),
        AC_Name varchar(30)
    )

    insert into @RenewalActivity(Membership_Type, Member_ID, Chapter, Full_Name, Transaction_Date, Renewal_Date, AC_ID, AC_Name)
    exec @sqlCommand @Coord_ID

    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temprenewals') is not null
        drop table ##temprenewals

    select * into ##temprenewals from @RenewalActivity

    set @qry = 'select * from ##temprenewals'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'Admin',
        @recipients = @Coord_Email,
        @query = @qry,
        @execute_query_database = 'TOPS',
        @subject = 'New Members and Renewals',
        @body = @emailBody,
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_attachment_filename='coord-s-9.csv',
        @query_result_separator=@tab,
        @query_result_no_padding=1

    fetch next from @CoordCursor into @Coord_ID,@Coord_Name, @Coord_Email
END

close @CoordCursor
deallocate @CoordCursor
```

1st issue; the recipients receive the report contains all the data. as they should receive just what it related to them 
example:

```
 Member_ID | Chapter |Coord_Email
 --------------------------------------
 1         |  A05    |  Coord2@Email.com
 5         |  A01    |  Coord1@Email.com
 8         |  A05    |  Coord2@Email.com
 12        |  A01    |  Coord1@Email.com
```

Currently 1,5,8 and 12 go to Coord1 and Coord2. the intention is 5 and 12 associated with A01 go to Coord1 and  1 and 8 go to Coord2.

2nd issue; the db mail is successfully  queued as it stated in the log with 35 recipients. However, not all the recipients was included in the mail. Out of 90 recipients only 35 received the emails. i checked the 1st query and it resulted all the recipients "90".

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure using sp\_send\_dbmail to send emails to multiple recipients queried from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111503/stored-procedure-using-sp-send-dbmail-to-send-emails-to-multiple-recipients-quer)

Comment: there's no duplicate SP.

Comment: Try setting @emailBody to null after BEGIN.

Comment: What is `exec @sqlCommand @Coord_ID` ?   It's not any valid tsql syntax that I'm aware of.

Comment: @TabAlleman it executes the sp_MZ_Get procedure

Comment: Kostis that's right and the @Coord_ID is a variable of Coord_ID.