# Sending email dynamically to multiple recipients with message using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Actually i am looking to send Birthday greetings to the members. The recipients list i am getting dynamically. With the below query i can send the greetings to the members.

```
DECLARE @emails VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @bodycontent VARCHAR(500)
SET @emails = '' 
SET @bodycontent = ''
use dnname
SELECT @emails = @emails + cm.PersonalEmail + ';' FROM tblIndividualMst  im
       inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
       where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
DECLARE @recipList VARCHAR(500)
SET @recipList =  (select SUBSTRING(@emails, 0, LEN(@emails)))
SELECT @bodycontent = 'Happy BirthDay to'+ ' ' + + @bodycontent + 
       im.FullName + '' FROM tblIndividualMst  im
       inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
       where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
use msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='eMail Profile',
    @recipients=@recipList,
    @subject='Happy Birthday',
    @body=@bodycontent, 
    @body_format = 'text'
```

So, if @emails have multiple recipients, how can i send the message to each members.

```
DECLARE @emails VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @bodycontent VARCHAR(500)
SET @emails = '' 
SET @bodycontent = ''
use dnname
SELECT @emails = @emails + cm.PersonalEmail + ';' FROM tblIndividualMst  im
       inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
       where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
DECLARE @recipList VARCHAR(500)
SET @recipList =  (select SUBSTRING(@emails, 0, LEN(@emails)))
SELECT @Count = @Count + Count(cm.PersonalEmail) FROM tblIndividualMst  im
       inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
       where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)

Declare @i int
set @i = 0
while @i <= @Count 
  begin
SELECT @bodycontent = 'Happy BirthDay to'+ ' ' + + @bodycontent + 
       im.FullName + '' FROM tblIndividualMst  im
       inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
       where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
use msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='eMail Profile',
   @recipients=@recipList,
   @subject='Happy Birthday',
   @body=@bodycontent,  
   @body_format = 'text'
end
```

So, how can i modify my query. Any help appreciated, thanks !!!

Comment: Did you test the code you posted? It looks like it is going to do it. recipList should get updated with the @emails (which are correctly separated by ; )  this should work, are you getting any error?

Comment: Yeah..I didn't get any error. But i didn't receive email. @RigertaDemiri

Comment: Do you get the email when having only one email address in the recipList?

Comment: Yeah, I got when having only one email @RigertaDemiri

Comment: Good, this means your issue is how you fill the `@recipList`. Check it's value and see if you have any missing values/characters or so.

Comment: I think your issue is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111503/stored-procedure-using-sp-send-dbmail-to-send-emails-to-multiple-recipients-quer)

Comment: Have you setup and tested sp_send_dbmail correctly? Try mailing yourself using fixed parameters. Have you checked the contents of the variables? Add a few print statements to see if they get set correctly. Remove `use msdb` from while loop and use `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` instead. Replace `@Count + Count(cm.PersonalEmail)` with `COUNT(1)`

Comment: added the print statements to test. But the print statement inside while loop is not printing anything @MWillemse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some observations...

1. You haven't declared `@Count` in your code anywhere. It would need to be declared as `INT` and set to `0`
2. In your `WHILE LOOP` you aren't incrementing `@Count` so this loop is infinite
3. I would make `@emails varchar(max)` to avoid truncation of the recipient list
4. `@recipList` is pointless as far as I can tell... you are setting it to the `substring` starting at 0 and going the entire length of all the emails... this is the same of saying `set @recipList = @emails`
5. Your while loop isn't constructed logically with how you want this to work. It seems like your intent is to send a single email with all of the names who have a birthday. First, I would comma separate these names in @body. Secondly you don't need a loop for this at all. Remove the `WHILE` loop since all you need to do is send the email once, to the list of `@recipList` you have built, with the `@bodycontent` you are concatenating.

With that all being said... your code can be simplified to the below which should work.

```
use dnname

DECLARE @emails VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @bodycontent VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @people varchar(max) 
SET @emails = '' 
SET @people = ''
SET @bodycontent = ''



SELECT @emails = @emails + cm.PersonalEmail + ';' FROM tblIndividualMst  im
       inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
       where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)


SELECT @people = @people + im.FullName + ', ' 
       FROM tblIndividualMst  im
       inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
       where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)

SELECT @bodycontent = 'Happy BirthDay to '+ @people

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                           @profile_name='eMail Profile',
                           @recipients=@emails,
                           @subject='Happy Birthday',
                           @body=@bodycontent,  
                           @body_format = 'text'
```

**IF you want to send one, personalized email, for each person... you can use a cursor**

```
use dnname

DECLARE @emails VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @bodycontent VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @people varchar(4000) 
SET @emails = '' 
SET @people = ''
SET @bodycontent = ''

DECLARE emailCursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT cm.PersonalEmail,im.FullName 
FROM tblIndividualMst  im
inner join tblContactMst cm on cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
where im.GroupID = 4673 and im.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)

OPEN emailCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM emailCursor INTO  @emails, @people

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @bodycontent = 'Happy BirthDay to '+ @people

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                           @profile_name='eMail Profile',
                           @recipients=@emails,
                           @subject='Happy Birthday',
                           @body=@bodycontent,  
                           @body_format = 'text'

FETCH NEXT FROM emailCursor INTO  @emails, @people



END
CLOSE emailCursor
DEALLOCATE emailCursor
```

Comment: When i tried without loop, the email i received like "Happy BirthDay to Name1, Name2,.....etc". But i am expecting like "Happy BirthDay to Name1" for first email recipient","Happy BirthDay to Name2" for second email recipient" and so on @scsimon

Comment: Ok I'll show you how to do that tomorrow when I'm at a desktop but I have showed you your current error. Check back tomorrow

Comment: Okay..Thanks @scsimon

Comment: @Muzz see the edit (the last one with the cursor). That is what you want to do.

Comment: it works, But keep on sending emails.. So for i received 100 + emails @scsimon

Comment: @Muzz I forgot a single line of code which I've now added. It should work now

Comment: It works great, like what i expected. Thanks @scsimon

Comment: Ok awesome @Muzz

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm opposed to using loops in SQL and therefor try to avoid them as much as possible. The idea behind this is to perform as little statements as possible. In this case I'd generate a piece of dynamic SQL and execute that.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = CAST((
    SELECT [text()] = REPLACE(REPLACE('
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name=''eMail Profile'',
            @recipients=''{email}'',
            @subject=''Happy Birthday'',
            @body=''Happy BirthDay to {fullname}'',  
            @body_format = ''text'';
    '
    ,'{fullname}',im.FullName)
    ,'{email}',cm.PersonalEmail)
    FROM tblIndividualMst  im
        INNER JOIN tblContactMst cm 
            ON cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
    WHERE im.GroupID = 4673 
        AND im.DateOfBirth = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS NVARCHAR(max));
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

---

Let me explain what I'm doing here:

Declare @SQL and assign result the of the query casted to NVARCHAR(max).

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = CAST((
```

XML engine is used to concat strings which is way faster than using normal contattenation, [text()] makes sure no XML tags will surround the SQL code.

```
    SELECT [text()] = REPLACE(REPLACE('
```

This is a template of the SQL code to be generated with placeholders that will be replaced.

```
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name=''eMail Profile'',
            @recipients=''{email}'',
            @subject=''Happy Birthday'',
            @body=''Happy BirthDay to {fullname}'',  
            @body_format = ''text'';
    '
```

Replacing placeholders
        ,'{fullname}',im.FullName)
        ,'{email}',cm.PersonalEmail)
The query that will define how much iterations are needed.

```
    FROM tblIndividualMst  im
        INNER JOIN tblContactMst cm 
            ON cm.ContactID = im.ContactID
    WHERE im.GroupID = 4673 
        AND im.DateOfBirth = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Tell SQL to generate XML for this query but by suppying an empty string and using [text()] we've made sure no tags are actually included in the result.

```
    FOR XML PATH('')
```

Cast XML to NVARCHAR(max)

```
) AS NVARCHAR(max));
```

And finally execute!

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```