# Send different query results to different recipients using DBMail

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I have been asked to create a job to run daily which sends a list of todays shipments to each customer.
I have a table with required detail of 'todays shipments' and the customers email addresses
[Cust E-Mail],[Ship No],[Item Number], [Qty],[Sell-to Customer No_],[Sell-to Customer Name],[Package Tracking No_]
I am quite familiar with using Dbmail for sending HTML emails however I do not know how I can loop through the relevant customers selecting their data and sending to their email address.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _how I can loop through the relevant customers_ You start by looping. How do you loop over a set of rows? Use a cursor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email dynamically to multiple recipients with message using sp\_send\_dbmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966038/sending-email-dynamically-to-multiple-recipients-with-message-using-sp-send-dbma)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This looks on the face of it to be close to what I need, thank you. However, I am unable to spend time on this right now and should return to it shortly.